# maven upload file to Nexus repo without groupId and artifactId

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, nexus, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a zip file and a Nexus repo and I would like to know if it is possible to create a goal to upload the zip file in the repot root folder, without groupId and artifactId

my artifact is build by a pom.xml

Comment: Is your Nexus repo a Maven repo? What are you trying to achieve by putting a zip in there that has no valid Maven coordinates?

Comment: Could you please explain what problem you want to solve by this? Why should the zip be at the root level?

Comment: I actually a bit confused why somebody puts a bounty on a question, but does not react to comments or answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the type of repository declared in your Nexus 3 instance.

For a Maven one, you need a GAV (group/artifactID/Version).
([`NEXUS-5170`](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-5170) is illustrates that, even without a GAV, the GUI still proposes '`Add Artifact`', but that is a bug)

In your case, as a workaround, you would create one "default/root" group dedicated to host those kind of artifacts: one group to host them all.
You can then use [`deploy:deploy-file`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html), which, [as you have seen, requires a GAV](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63504381/6309).

But if your artifact is built by a `pom.xml` (which does specify the GAV), a simple [`mvn deploy`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html) is enough  (target `deploy:deploy`)